# Show file dates from MTP device?

Tags: windows, android, mtp

When I connect my [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) device (Android phone) via USB to my Windows 10 PC, open it in Windows Explorer, and set the `View` to `Details`, it does not show the file dates. Is there a way to make it do so?

If not, why not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click one of the column headers in Explorer, and select to enable the "Created" and/or "Modified" columns.

[image: Select Columns]

Comment: `Modified` works. (I thought I had tried that before...) Do you know why `Created` shows nothing in the column when I add it?

Comment: Not sure off-hand, but the media format type may only support one date field.

Comment: It's frustrating too when "Moving" files off the MTP protocol, those `Created` file attributes assume the date the file was copied to the host computer, not the date the file was created on the mobile device. I'm glad that Android and other devices that actually use the timestamp as part of the filename so you can always discern that information there.

Comment: @jxramos Yes, that can be frustrating.  If you find a solution to that issue, please let us know.